# Why is my textarea not visible?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, textarea

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class text{
  public static void main(String Args[]){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
    panel.add(area);
    frame.add(panel);
  }
}
```

When I compile and run this it shows a JFrame and no textarea on it.

Answer (score 2):

You should first add all the components to the frame and then make it visible. Otherwise, adding components dynamically after the frame is visible requires revalidation and repaint. [See How to Make Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for more details.

[JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) has several constructors. The default constructor sets the number of rows and columns to 0 and empty text. In such case the text area may not be displayed. Use another constructor, ie: `textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);` See [How to Use Text Areas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for more details and examples.

Here is a small example:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextAreaDemo{
  public static void main(String Args[]){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextAreaDemo");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            JTextArea area = new JTextArea(5, 20);
            panel.add(area);
            frame.add(panel);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the panel to the frame.

Comment: I meant to do that in the post. I fixed that problem, but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

There were some little things missing from your code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
area.setVisible(true);
area.setSize(100, 100);
panel.add(area);
frame.add(panel); 
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

The main difference between what you had and what I have is setting the area visible and the size of that area. I think that was all you were missing. Here is a link for extra help: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-jtextarealp: